# Android studio: como organizar imagens em subpasta

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

ao colocar as imagens em uma nova subpasta do drawable, as imagens e a novo pasta deixa de aparecer no no painel esquerdo, na aba "android", já nas outras aba como "Packages" a pasta está lá.

[image: Aba Packages mostrando a pasta]

[image: Aba Android mostrando apenas as imagens soltas]

Answer (score 1):

O android studio só reconhece as seguintes sub-pastas de drawable:

**Sub-pastas de dimensão de imagem:**

drawable-hdpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-xxhdpi

- Neste caso, o android verifica qual é o melhor formato de imagem para poder executar no seu aplicativo instalado no dispositivo.

**Sub-pastas de versão:**

versões anteriores...

drawable-v16

drawable-v17

drawable-v18

drawable-v19

versões superiores....

- imagens contidas nestes drawable de versões só serão mostradas em dispositivos com a mesma versão de API.

No seu caso, suas imagens JPEG só serão mostradas em dispositivos cuja a versão de API é 24 pois estão contidas na pasta "drawable-v24".